# Ajax success function class is adding on every element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am building an Ajax function to implement *search functionalities* and the search function is working fine, but on `success:` function **I am trying to add class on whole searched element** - but the class is adding on every element.

```js
$('#id_search_tag').keyup(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'searchTag' %}",
    data: {
      'w': $('#id_search_tag').val(),
    },
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      for (result of response.results) {
        $('#tags_list').prepend(`
    <div id="tags-browser" class="grid-layout">
        <div class="mySearchedTags">
               <div class="d-flex jc-space-between ai-center mb12">
                <div class="flex--item">
                    <a href="/answers/tag/tag" class="post-tag" >${result.tagName}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
       `)
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="tags_list">
  <div id="tags-browser" class="grid-layout">
    <div class="mySearchedTags">
      <div class="d-flex jc-space-between ai-center mb12">
        <div class="flex--item">
          <a href="/answers/tag/tag" class="post-tag">{{tag}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**In Inspect Element** it is showing `<div id="tags-browser" class="grid-layout">` on every element like:

```
<div id="tags-browser" class="grid-layout">
    <div class="mySearchedTags">
  ....
   ....
    ....

<div id="tags-browser" class="grid-layout">
    <div class="mySearchedTags">
  ....
   ....
    ....
```

But **I am trying to add only on top** like:

```
<div id="tags-browser" class="grid-layout">
    <div class="mySearchedTags">
        ....
        ....

    <div class="mySearchedTags">
        ....
        ....

    <div class="mySearchedTags">
        ....
        ....

</div>
```

I have tried many times, but it is still adding on every element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the first div outside the loop.
Here I use map and join and destruct the tagName to improve readability

```js
$('#tags_list').prepend(`<div id="tags-browser" class="grid-layout">
  ${response.results.map(({tagName}) => `<div class="mySearchedTags">
            <div class="d-flex jc-space-between ai-center mb12">
                <div class="flex--item">
                    <a href="/answers/tag/tag" class="post-tag" >${tagName}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`).join("")}
    </div>`)
```

Comment: Thanks It Worked Perfectly. But Can you elaborate , Why did you use `response.results.map` inbuilt function ?

Comment: Why not? It is simpler  - especially in your case - I can destruct the tagName and apart from the .join("") it seems more tidy to me

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What did you change and why? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69908979/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: See update. Not much to explain. Moved a div